# JavaScript and PHP sessions

Tags: javascript, php, session, authentication

My login.php looks like:

```html
if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['username'] = "1";
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        ob_start();

        $url = 'main.php';

        while (ob_get_status()) 
        {
            ob_end_clean();
        }
        header( "Location: $url" );
    }
}
else {
    $_SESSION['username']='';
}
```

and when I succesfully log in, main.php redirects me to login.php instead of running the game loop.

```html
<?php
if(!(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username']!='')) {
    echo "<script>window.location.href=\"login.php\"</script>";
}
else {
echo "<script defer>reload();</script>";
}
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: In you `if` you are doing something like `if (1!=1 AND 1=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try instead

```
<?php
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
 echo "<script>window.location.href=\"login.php\"</script>";
}
else {
echo "<script defer>reload();</script>";
}
```

`Empty`checks

`"" (an empty string)`
`0 (0 as an integer)`
`0.0 (0 as a float)`
`"0" (0 as a string)`
`NULL`
`FALSE`
`array() (an empty array)`
`$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)`

or do `$_SESSION['username']==''` check.

Comment: Hey, thanks for response but it's still redirecting even I logged in successfully.

Comment: have you started the session on main.php??

Comment: When I do I get:
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Comment: add `session_start` at the top of the page after `<?php` opens.

Comment: I did and the page runs normally but I don't see any output from reload.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64624/discussion-between-martin1993-03-and-sgt).

Answer (score 1):

I think your main php code should change like this..

```
<?php
if(!(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username']=='')) {
    echo "<script>window.location.href=\"login.php\"</script>";
}
else {
echo "<script defer>reload();</script>";
}
?>
```

here you are checking `$_SESSION['username']!=''`

Need to change that to..

```
if(!(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username']==''))
```

Comment: it's still redirecting even if it's a sucessfull login